# JavaFX Listview - disable edit on double click?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an esitable listview in my application, that should ONLY switch to edit-mode, when an external button is pressed. But when i make the listview editable, the edit-event is also triggered, when i perform a double-click over the listcell. How can i prevent a listcell from switching to edit-mode when i perform a double-click on it?

Comment: Please explain how the button is supposed to work. Do you want the button to toggle editable mode or do you want to press the button and enter edit mode directly? If you want the latter, how do you choose which cell to edit? Please show some of your code.

Comment: There isn't any code yet ... But it should work by selecting a listcell, and when i press the button some changes in the cell shall be made (like setting a graphic or changing the text)

Comment: I like the answer given but what I do is on right click of a cell, I open an alert with a textbox. When okay is pressed on the alert, it updates the cell.

Comment: Using your current ideas, I would enable edit on double click and disable edit on Enter pressed on a focused cell or lose of focus.

Answer (score 3):

Have the `ListView` be non-editable and only set it editable to edit the selected cell when the button is pressed.

Notice also how the button is disabled via a binding when no item is selected.

See the edit method in the MCVE:

## Controller.java

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldListCell;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> list;

    @FXML
    private Button editSelectedItem;

    public void initialize() {
        list.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
        list.setEditable(false);
        list.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("a", "b", "c"));

        editSelectedItem.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
                () -> list.getSelectionModel().isEmpty(),
                list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
        ));
    }

    @FXML
    public void edit(final ActionEvent event) {
        if (!list.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()) {
            list.setEditable(true);
            list.edit(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
            list.setEditable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

## Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

## sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox fx:controller="Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <ListView fx:id="list"/>
    <Button onAction="#edit" text="Edit selected item" fx:id="editSelectedItem"/>
</VBox>
```